# Find equal width intervals and intervals mean

Tags: r

I have a dataset (kl):

```
Actual
4096
-1149
13780
744
-461
9660
619
3466
0
7675
10446
12452
10813
11637
-1908
0
7441
11981
5389
4717
```

Then I apply classInt package to have equal width intervals:

```
library(classInt)

y = classIntervals(kl$Actual, 6, style = 'quantile')

y
style: quantile
          [-1908,0)        [0,1651.333)     [1651.333,5053)     [5053,8998.333) 
              3                   4                   3                   3 
[8998.333,11499.67)    [11499.67,13780] 
              3                   4
```

Then I have to store these intervals so as to match it with Actual i.e. each number lies within which interval. Example: 4096 lies within (1651.333,5053).

Then I want to have mean of intervals in seperate column i.e. Interval_Mean. Example: (1651.333 + 5053)/2 = 3352.17 .

Now I want new dataframe (nm) as:

```
nm
Actual  Interval            Interval_Mean
4096    1651.333,5053        3352.17
-1149   -1908,0              -954.00
13780   11499.67,13780       12639.84
744     0,1651.333           825.67
-461    -1908,0             -954.00
9660    8998.333,11499.67    10249.00
619      0,1651.333          825.67
3466    1651.333,5053        3352.17
0        0,1651.333          825.67
7675    5053.00,8998.333     7025.67
10446   8998.333,11499.67    10249.00
12452   11499.67,13780       12639.84
10813   8998.333,11499.67    10249.00
11637   11499.67,13780       12639.84
-1908      -1908,0           -954.00
0           0,1651.333       825.67
7441    5053.00,8998.333     7025.67
11981   11499.67,13780       12639.84
5389    5053.00,8998.333     7025.67
4717    1651.333,5053        3352.17
```

Where, Interval is the o/p of y above aligned with values of Actual and Interval_Mean is the mean of each intervals.

Thanks for providing the solution.

Comment: You can add to your answer some trials you did.

Comment: The number of intervals giving a max count of `n` would just be `ceiling(length(kl$Actual)/n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various techniques ultimately I got the solution:

```
z = unique(y$brks)

kl$interval = cut(kl$Actual, breaks = z, right = FALSE )

kl$interval = gsub("\\[|\\)", "", kl$interval)

intmean = within(kl, interval<-data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(interval), ',', fixed=TRUE))))

intmean = intmean[,-1]

str(intmean)

intmean[sapply(intmean, is.factor)] <- lapply(intmean[sapply(intmean, is.factor)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

intmean$interval_mean = apply(intmean, 1,mean)

nm = kl

nm$Interval_Mean = intmean$interval_mean
```

And we reach the solution. Thanks!!